# Problem with python soap library suds. Wsdl was not understood

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

The code below throw a SAXParseException: "mismatched tag":

```
from suds.client import Client <br>
url = 'http://www.didww.com/api/?wsdl'
client = Client(url, cache=None)      
print client
```

Is it problem with suds, or there is some errors in wsdl?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the WSDL file in a browser or XML viewer? That should answer your question as to whether the problem is in the wsdl. The exception suggests there is something up with it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for me, suds 0.3.3 (without cache option - None is not a valid option for cache in my version of suds):

```
In [4]: from suds.client import Client
In [5]: url = 'https://xml.192.com/IDSearch.cfc?wsdl'
In [6]: c = Client(url)
In [7]: print c

Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.3.3 GA  build:     R413-20081204

Service ( IDSearch ) tns="http://corpwsdl.oneninetwo"
Prefixes (1)
  ns0 = "http://rpc.xml.coldfusion"
Ports (1):
  (IDSearch.cfc)
     Methods (1):
        search(xs:string xml, )
     Types (1):
        ns0:CFCInvocationException
```

Comment: sorry, i have problem with this wsdl: "http://www.didww.com/api/?wsdl"
"https://xml.192.com/IDSearch.cfc?wsdl" works fine

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce your problem but all works for me.

i'm using suds 0.4

running

```
from suds.client import Client

client = Client('http://api.didww.com/api/index.php?wsdl', cache=None)

print client
```

gives

```
Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.4 GA  build: R699-20100913

Service ( DID World Wide ) tns="urn:didww"
Prefixes (2)
  ns0 = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  ns1 = "urn:didww"
Ports (1):
  (DID World WidePort)
     Methods (11):

    buildmapping(xs:string auth_string, xs:int did_id,   xs:string map_proto,s:string map_uri, xs:int add_did, )
        change_mapping(xs:string auth_string, xs:string did_number, xs:string map_proto, xs:string map_uri, xs:int add_did, )
        did_cancel(xs:string auth_string, xs:string did_number, )
        get_did_details(xs:string auth_string, xs:string did_number, )
        get_region_details(xs:string auth_string, xs:string uniq, )
        getcities(xs:string auth_string, xs:int country_id, )
        getcountries(xs:string auth_string, )
        new_order_renew(xs:string auth_string, xs:string did_number, xs:int period, xs:int autorenew, )
        neworder(xs:string auth_string, xs:string hashkey, xs:string uniq, xs:int autorenew, xs:int period, )
        order_autorenew_status(xs:string auth_string, xs:string did_number, xs:int status, )
        order_cancel(xs:string auth_string, xs:string did_number, )
     Types (55):
        ns0:Array
        CitiesArray
        City
        CountriesArray
        Country
        DID
        DID_data
        ns0:ENTITIES
        ns0:ENTITY
        ns0:ID
        ns0:IDREF
        ns0:IDREFS
        ns0:NCName
        ns0:NMTOKEN
        ns0:NMTOKENS
        ns0:NOTATION
        ns0:Name
        ns0:QName
        Region
        ns0:Struct
        ns0:anyURI
        ns0:arrayCoordinate
        ns0:base64
        ns0:base64Binary
        ns0:boolean
        ns0:byte
        ns0:date
        ns0:dateTime
        ns0:decimal
        ns0:double
        ns0:duration
        ns0:float
        ns0:gDay
        ns0:gMonth
        ns0:gMonthDay
        ns0:gYear
        ns0:gYearMonth
        ns0:hexBinary
        ns0:int
        ns0:integer
        ns0:language
        ns0:long
        ns0:negativeInteger
        ns0:nonNegativeInteger
        ns0:nonPositiveInteger
        ns0:normalizedString
        ns0:positiveInteger
        ns0:short
        ns0:string
        ns0:time
        ns0:token
        ns0:unsignedByte
        ns0:unsignedInt
        ns0:unsignedLong
        ns0:unsignedShort
```

I guess they had a broken wsdl file for a bit, but all seems fine now

hope that helps